# Possible to create watch face for Apple Watch?

Tags: ios, app-store, watchkit, apple-watch

I've googled over the internet, still can't find an official answer.
I can see I can make build glance scenes, but those are "hidden" one swipe away from the user beneath actual watch face.

Are developers allowed to publish watch faces?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is not possible.  In the Apple WatchKit forums, an Apple evangelist links to this thread for the FAQ on creating a custom watch face.

https://devforums.apple.com/thread/254629?tstart=15

Here is the link to the "official" WatchKit FAQ https://devforums.apple.com/thread/254675?tstart=0

Technically, you could create an app that is a watch, but it wouldn't be a watch face.

Comment: I wonder with the new native app support for Apple Watch if this is going possible or not. http://thenextweb.com/apple/2015/06/08/developers-can-now-build-native-apps-for-the-apple-watch-using-watchkit/ But it still sounds like a "no", except for that "complications" thing which just lets us add some text to existing faces (?)

Comment: No, it is still not possible with watchOS 2.  The ClockKit reference shows you what you can do on the watch face as a third party developer. https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/watchos/documentation/ClockKit/Reference/ClockKit_framework/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016082

Comment: "Technically, you could create an app that is a watch" - I believe Apple will reject it if you do.

Comment: You could make the App look like a watch face. But Apple is likely going to reject it if it looks too much like the main watch face. you can design complications to be added to the existing available watch faces though. to place your app on the main watch face.

Answer (score 4):

I wanted to write my own watch face too - but for a hobby project, I don't think Apple allow time-centric apps for the Apple Watch on the App store at the moment.  The App I've written works well as a watch face, but doesn't support complications/glances (which you'd get if it was an official watch face).  I've blogged about how to write it here, with some code snippets in Swift: https://musingstudio.com/2016/08/04/how-to-write-a-watch-face-app-for-apple-watch/

Comment: From the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer): Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.