# How to create our own Watch face to our app?

Tags: ios, swift, watch

Are we able to create our own watch face to our application. We have ios app and watch app, need to create watch face with few app data's like heart rate, steps count, etc on the watch face.

But I fount some answers like it is not possible to create a watch face.
[Possible to create watch face for Apple Watch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29370806/possible-to-create-watch-face-for-apple-watch)

Are developers allowed to publish watch faces?

I have found a website [Facer](https://www.facer.io/creator), where they are offering customizing options and generating .watchface from their website. What approach they are following?

Comment: Refer -> https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/739074